# convert to local time based on other time zone flutter

Tags: flutter

I went user to select some time zone and select date base this time zone then convert this date to equivelent date in local

I went user to select some time zone and select date base this time zone then convert this date to equivelent date in local

Comment: add a snippet for your code

Answer (score 0):

The [package:timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) is good for that.  The docs are decent, and there are examples you can find with google.